# Standard practices for graphing large datasets in android

Tags: android, graphics, graph, android-canvas

I have an android app that collects data and I need to graph that data.  The dataset could be a few hundred samples, to tens of thousands.  The X axis is time. The Y axis can have 1 to 15 different sets of data.

I've looked into some graphing libraries such as achartengine, but they all seem to expect that your graph will have a fairly compact dataset that fits nicely in a screen.  With 20k samples, my graph will be much wider than it is tall.  Actually I never really want the Y axis taller than the screen, the zoom should zoom only in the X axis.

My ideal interface is basically like a sideways listview that you can just fling left or right to scroll the really wide graph.  Zoom will simply compress or expand the time scale.

In any case, my question is what are the best practices when trying to do something like this? I can find graphing tutorials, but nothing that addresses this problem specifically. It would seem very wasteful to try and render the whole graph at once.  But I want the slide navigation to be smooth. Will drawing a screen at a time to the canvas be fast enough for a smooth scroll?  Or will I have to go to openGL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hear users of AChartEngine mentioning that they add tens of thousands of data values in the model and AChartEngine still handles and displays them fine.

Comment: I actually tried this and it slowed to a crawl.  Seems it has to iterate the whole dataset before it renders it making the user wait tens of seconds before it displays large datasets.

Comment: Same Problem over here. I also have to display, like 10 Sets of Data with up to 2000 Points. Android Plot and Graphview seems to be really slow on my Moto G when it comes to initialization or pinch and zoom .. i think i will give AChartEngine a try.